# TinyMCE auto-formatting wrecking <ins> and <del> tags

Tags: html, tinymce

I'm trying to keep code such as

```
<ins>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah2</p>
</ins>
```

intact when I paste into TinyMCE. Unfortunately it automatically turns this into

```
<ins>
</ins>
<p>blah</p>
<p>blah2</p>
```

How can I keep it from auto-formatting the ins tag? Is there a plugin or something that could help?

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce uses a [root htlm element](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aforced_root_block) this can be set to another element.
It is necessary to have text wrapped into paragraphs in order to be able to style them.

Another problem is you won't be able to get Paragraphs into `ins`-tags because the browser won't let you (`p` wrapped into ins is not valid HTML);